# how to convert a resulted string to hex string in php

Tags: php, hex

How to convert resulted string to hexstring. 
For example bytes of values 0x05 and 0x1d should results in a tring 051d ? in PHP ?

Thanks

Comment: `$x = 'ABC';

$len = strlen($x);
for ($i=0; $i <= $len; $i +=2) {
    echo sprintf('0x%X', ord($x[$i])), PHP_EOL;
}
`

Comment: What is "resulted string"? Result of what?